# Extract the database abstraction layer

Tags: 7, database

If it's possible, how can I go about extracting the database abstraction layer to use in a non-Drupal site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to use the Drupal database API exactly as it currently exists, or do you just like the idea of a PDO abstraction layer?

If you're really trying to break out of Drupal's bootstrap and code, then check out using PHP Data Objects (PDO):

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Now, if you just want to use Drupal's database API to work with a database outside of Drupal's database (but within a custom module or within a custom .php file that bootstraps the database), you can really easily do so by switching databases via `db_set_active()`. You'd throw something like this in your settings.php file:

```
<?php
$databases = array();
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  // Drupal's credentials here...
);
$databases['my_other_db']['default'] = array(
  // My other database credentials here...
);
?>
```

and then you'd activate it via:

```
<?php
db_set_active('my_other_db'); // Use my_other_db
// do stuff using Drupal 7's awesome database API
db_set_active(); // Go back to Drupal's db.
?>
```

I wrote a blog post that sums up how to bootstrap Drupal in a standalone PHP script to use certain layers, you may find this useful:  -

- http://www.csdesignco.com/content/using-drupal-data-functions-and-session-variables-external-php-script

Comment: I realize this answer is a few years old, but do you happen to still have the content of the blog post?

Comment: @ianmac45 see http://csdv.co/legacy-blog/using-drupal-data-functions-and-session-variables-in-an-external-php-script.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the Drupal database code in a website, without bootstrapping Drupal, you need the following files:

- includes/database/database.inc
- includes/database/sqlite/database.inc
- includes/database/mysql/database.inc
- includes/database/pgsql/database.inc

The code in those files needs to be changed, as:

- The code uses the [DRUPAL_ROOT](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/constant/DRUPAL_ROOT/7) constant. You could remove the code using that constant, and replace it with code that automatically loads the include file containing the class. For example, the following code uses `DRUPAL_ROOT` because Drupal cannot use its code registry until there isn't a database connection active, as its code registry uses a database table.

  ```
  // We cannot rely on the registry yet, because the registry requires an
  // open database connection.
  $driver_class = 'DatabaseConnection_' . $driver;
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/database/' . $driver . '/database.inc';
  $new_connection = new $driver_class(self::$databaseInfo[$key][$target]);
  $new_connection->setTarget($target);
  $new_connection->setKey($key);
  ```

  It could be rewritten as follows, if you register your own function with [spl_autoload_register()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

  ```
  $driver_class = 'DatabaseConnection_' . $driver;
  $new_connection = new $driver_class(self::$databaseInfo[$key][$target]);
  $new_connection->setTarget($target);
  $new_connection->setKey($key);
  ```
- The functions use the global `$databases`, which is normally defined in the settings.php file. You could replace that variable with a static property of the [Database](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/Database/7) class.